# Firefox font issue

Tags: firefox, fonts

I am having an issue with rendering my embedded font in Firefox. It works and looks nice and crisp on Webkit but not in Firefox. I'm using latest versions in both browsers in OS X.

```
@font-face{
    font-family:AvantGardeM;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    src:url("../font/AvantGardeM.eot");
    src:local("â˜º"), 
        url("../font/AvantGardeM.ttf") format("truetype"), 
        url("../font/AvantGardeM.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("../font/AvantGardeM.svg") format("svg")
}
```

I'm also attaching a sample screenshot. First one is Chrome, second and third is Firefox. 
[image]

I've noticed small issues with some images too. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe its a bug in firefox itself.

Comment: Probably not. Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my external display's display adapter.